# what's different between os.system(' ') and commands.getstatusoutput(' ') in python on linux?

Tags: python

what's different between `os.system(' ')` and `commands.getstatusoutput(' ')` in python on linux?

I would be really thankful if you could give an example.

thanks

Comment: Check their documentation and don't use either of them. [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` runs the external shell command and returns an integer which is 0 for success and any other value is failure. If the command being ran sends something to stdout or stderr it will only be printed but you cannot assign that to a variable.

`command.getstatusoutput` does the same "pretty much" thing that `os.system` does and returns a tuple with the status code integer being the first element and the status message being the second element.

Under the hood, `command.getstatusoutput` does things differently than `os.system`. It uses the `os` module. It uses `os.popen` in particular and redirects all `stderr` output to be combined with `stdout` output and reads the status message from `stdout`.

It must be said that the `subprocess` module is the new way of doing whatever these two commands above can do and much more.